# Parser and Input plugin for system logs in fluentbit

Tags: parsing, logging, input, system

I would like to learn how to write the configuration for system logs using an input plugin and its corresponding parser. By the way I am sending logs to opensearch output plugin is fine.I am new to this and would appreciate any guidance.couldn’t find anything useful in internet.Thank you.

I have tried /var/log/system*.log in the path.